# Javascript countdown timer with multiple use

Tags: javascript, php

I have a java-script countdown function that works perfectly, but always shows only one result. What I want is that just like in php, I give a value (in our case the time left) and then it starts counting down. I want to show different count down timers on the same page, but this seems to be a larger issue then I thought and sadly couldn't find the answer alone :/

This is the function I use, can anyone help me modify it, so that I get what I desire?

After the first answer here, I still don't get what I want :( This is what I have and tried:

My php function:

```
function count_down_timer($time,$id) {

    echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\"><!--

        var count = $time;
        var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

        function timer() {

            count=count-1;

            var h = Math.floor(count/3600);
            var m = Math.floor(count % 3600/60);

            if(h == 1) { var h_txt = h + ' hour'; } else if(h > 1) { var h_txt = h + ' hours'; } else { var h_txt = ''; }
            if(m == 1) { var m_txt = m + ' minute'; } else if(m > 1) { var m_txt = m + ' minutes'; } else { var m_txt = '< 1 minute'; }
            if(h > 0 && m > 0) { var and = ' and '; } else { var and = ''; }

            document.getElementById(\"$id\").innerHTML = h_txt + and + m_txt;
        }
    //--></script>";

}
```

My outcome:

```
<?php

count_down_timer(1000,'timer');
count_down_timer(4000,'test');

?>

<span id="timer"></span><p>
<span id="test"></span>
```

both give the latest time of 4000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the code is not working is because you only have a single global variable named `count`. Therefore, the timer value gets changed to 4000 the second time `count_down_timer()` is called. If you want to keep two separate counts, you should give your count variables different names.

I would also echo your javascript `timer()` function once only. It does not need to be echoed for each time you want it run.

In addition, I would completely modify your php function so that all it would do is the following:

```
<?php 
function count_down_timer($time,$id){
  echo "var ".$id."Count = $time;
  setInterval(function(){ 
    ".$id."Count = ".$id."Count - 1;
    timer(".$id."Count, '$id');
  }, 1000);";
}
?>
```

So that you could then say:

```
 <?php 
   count_down_timer(1000, 'test');
   count_down_timer(4000, 'timer');
 ?>
```

Here would be the goal for your final output (I added the counter just so you could see it working):

```js
function timer(count, id) {


  var h = Math.floor(count / 3600);
  var m = Math.floor(count % 3600 / 60);

  var h_txt = '';
  var m_txt = '';
  if (h == 1) {
    h_txt = h + ' hour';
  } else if (h > 1) {
    h_txt = h + ' hours';
  }
  if (m == 1) {
    m_txt = m + ' minute';
  } else if (m > 1) {
    m_txt = m + ' minutes';
  } else {
    m_txt = '< 1 minute';
  }
  if (h > 0 && m > 0) {
    var and = ' and ';
  } else {
    var and = '';
  }
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = h_txt + and + m_txt + ' and count is ' + count;
}

var testCount = 1000;
setInterval(function() {
  testCount = testCount - 1;
  timer(testCount, 'test');
}, 1000);
var timerCount = 4000;
setInterval(function() {
  timerCount = timerCount - 1;
  timer(timerCount, 'timer');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="timer">
</span><p></p>
<span id="test"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! That gives the result I was looking for :D

Comment: Done :) Thanks a lot ForOhFor

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array to store the information in. Each element of the array would have the id of the span for that timer and the time left. The timer would decrement the time left for each timer every second.

Your PHP page would need to print an element in the array and a span for each timer.